# Expect script not running in docker container

Tags: bash, shell, docker, expect

I'm trying to run expect script in docker container. I've installed expect

Docker file

```
FROM ubuntu:latest

RUN apt-get update \
  && apt-get install expect -y
```

Expect script

```
eval spawn ssh -oStrictHostKeyChecking=no -oCheckHostIP=no user@****
#use correct prompt
set prompt ":|#|\\\$"
interact -o -nobuffer -re $prompt return
send "******\r"
interact
```

I get the following error

```
bash: spawn: command not found
```

Please help

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/802657/spawn-command-not-found-on-ubuntu-14-04

Answer (score 1):

`spawn` is an expect command, not a bash command. So, although you installed expect, you still cant call `spawn` directly from the shell

What you need to do is put all your expect code inside a file, for example `mycommand.expect` and then invoke it like this `expect mycommand.expect`. You can also add a shebang line to the beginning of your file like this `#!/path/to/expect`, then chmod that file like this `chmod a+x mycommand.expect` so that you can run it from shell like a normal command with just `mycommand.expect`